# avoid alphabet select in mysql select query

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying a mysql query on my PHP page and am in trouble.

```
$sql = 'SELECT calldate, clid, duration FROM cdr';
```

shows following values

```
Date:2014-06-14 19:43:18
CLI: "Name Surname" <5001>
Duration: 67

Date:2014-06-14 19:46:46
CLI: "Name Surname" <5001>
Duration: 43

Date:2014-06-15 12:52:56
CLI: 440012345678
Duration: 9

Date:2014-06-15 13:06:42
CLI: "440012345678" <440012345678>
Duration: 88
```

and

```
$sql = 'SELECT calldate, clid, duration FROM cdr WHERE clid REGEXP "^[0-9]+$"';
```

shows only

```
Date:2014-06-15 12:52:56
CLI: 440012345678
Duration: 9
```

Where as I want any result that matches following format "440012345678" <440012345678> just the format, not numbers.

What should I add to my query? Any help would be appreciated, I do not know much about MYSQL

Comment: Is the database actually storing the value `"440012345678" <440012345678>` or is that just your website indicating that it is a string rather than a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you are looking for would be:

```
SELECT calldate, clid, duration FROM cdr 
WHERE clid REGEXP "^\"[:alnum:]+\"[:blank:]<[:alnum:]+>$"
```

This would match all of the above except the simple "CLI: 440012345678".

Comment: I think the OP is trying to find anything with numbers, i.e. the last two results but not the first two.

Comment: Let's see what he's up to. REGEXP "^\"\d+\"(\s<\d+>)?$" would match those two.

Comment: @brainbowler MySQLs [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) is using POSIX syntax ...

Comment: well, not if there is no `"` in the value. Maybe something like `"^[\d\" <>]+$"`? Although I'm not sure why you would store the data like that in a SQL database.

Comment: @redbmk: Then it would be rather REGEXP "^((\"[0-9]+\")|[0-9]+)([:blank:]<[0-9]+>)?$", to be a bit stricter.

Comment: Hi boys! Thanks a lot for all the replies. I was actually lookin for 
    REGEXP "^[\d\" <> 0-9]+$"';
@brainbowler I will accept your answer, as your comments do have the syntax that helped me fetch my result. Thanks brainbowler and redbmk